# Change gallery thumbnails count & number of related products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce I would like to show 3 thumbnails on single product the gallery image slider and also to get displayed 3 related products only.

How to change gallery thumbnails count & number of related products in Woocommerce?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get 3 displayed thumbnails in the product image gallery you will use:

```
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_columns', 'three_product_thumbnails_columns', 10, 1 );
function three_product_thumbnails_columns( $columns ) {
    return 3; // Default is 4
}
```

To get 3 displayed related products:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', 'three_related_products', 10, 1 );
function three_related_products( $args ) {
    $args['posts_per_page'] = 3;
    $args['columns'] = 3;
    
    return $args;
}
```

Both codes goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks.It works fine.

Comment: Seems, this doesnt work anymore?